# Connect to Docker MySQL container from localhost?

Tags: mysql, macos, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker mysql image running, following is what the docker-compose.yml file looks like:

```
db:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
```

This works fine.

My question is: How can I connect to the MySQL instance running on that container from the command line mysql client on my the host (my macbook)?

To clarify:

- I have a macbook with Docker installed
- I have a docker container with mysql
- I want to connect to the mysql instance running on the aforementioned container from the Terminal on my macbook
- I do NOT want to user a `docker` command to make this possible. Rather, I want to use the `mysql` client directly from the Terminal (without tunneling in through a docker container).

I don't have MySQL running locally, so port 3306 should be open and ready to use.

The command I am using to start the container is: `docker-compose run`

Comment: This looks particularly relevant: http://serverfault.com/questions/688513/cant-access-mysql-docker-container-from-the-host

Comment: how is docker installed on your macbook? docker toolbox, boot2docker or kitematic?

Comment: `boot2docker`  The docker toolbox was unreliable.  I have open issues on their github, and if/when it becomes more stable I'll use it, but for now `boot2docker` is managing the VMs, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

## Using `docker-compose up`

Since you published port `3306` on your **docker host**, from that host itself you would connect to `127.0.0.1:3306`.

## Using `docker-compose run`

In that case the port mapping section of the `docker-compose.yml` file is ignored. To have the port mapping section considered, you have to add the [`--service-ports`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/#/run) option:

```
docker-compose run --service-ports db
```

## Additional note

Beware that by default, the mysql client tries to connect using a unix socket when you tell it to connect to `localhost`. So do use `127.0.0.1` and not `localhost`:

```
 $ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root
```

> Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
>   Your MySQL connection id is 1
>   Server version: 5.6.26 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
>
> Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>
> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
>   affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
>   owners.
>
> Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
>
> mysql>

```
$ mysql -h localhost -P 3306 -u root
```

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I tried using `127.0.0.1` (and `192.168.59.103`), neither worked :(

Comment: Any other ideas? @Thomasleveil

Comment: sorry I never used boot2docker myself. Maybe https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4007 will help

Comment: FWIW, I'm trying with `docker-machine` now ... unfortunately, I'm still stuck.  But, your link looks promising, so I'm trying that now.  Thanks for the help, regardless.

Comment: any advice on how this might work using Docker toolbox?  I'd be happy to ditch `boot2docker`

Comment: https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker#container-port-redirection might be it. Best of luck ;)

Comment: Ok, check this out: 

If I run the mysql server this way, I can connect fine: 
`docker run -p 0.0.0.0:3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=foo -d mysql`

The PORTS column looks like this when I run `docker ps`:
`0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp`

However, specifying the ports in docker compose as `- "0.0.0.0:3306:3306"` doesn't work.

The PORTS column looks like this, as opposed to the aforementioned example:
`3306/tcp`

Any idea on how to specify the ports in docker-compose so that it results in the 0.0.0.0 mapping?  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: make sure you have the latest version of docker-compose

Comment: Bah! got it!!  The answer is to use the `--service-ports` option when running docker-compose: `docker-compose run --service-ports db` (the original `docker-compose.yml` file works fine)

Couldn't have made it there without you!  Thanks for the pro tips!

Comment: please add to your question the original command line you were using to start the container `docker-compose run`. Then answer your own question and accept it so others can easily get to it

Comment: I tried connecting with 127.0.0.1 and got this error. Any ideas why? `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0`

Comment: Good stuff. Didn't know about the localhost vs 127.0.0.1 thing re: Mysql client. Appreciate that part especially.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 did not work for me either. I had to inspect the container and get the "IPAddress". ex. sudo docker inspect mysql-containerName and then use the IPAddress used there.

Comment: This command didn't work as-is for me, I had to update it as follows (note the -p at the end):

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p

Answer (score 19):

A simple way to login to MySQL inside a Docker image is:

`sudo docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> mysql -u root -p`

for mySQL's `root` account by default password is not set, its BLANK, just press enter/return key, unless you have changed root password.

On successful execution, above command gives you mysql prompt.

Cheers!

Comment: The original question very specifically states that they do NOT want to do this.

Answer (score 13):

I got it!! The answer is to use the `--service-ports` option when running `docker-compose`:

`docker-compose run --service-ports db` (the original docker-compose.yml file works fine)

Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: This worked, but now the container is unkillable?  How do you stop it?

Comment: that is similar when you define a service db in docker-compose file. It really not effecient -.-

Answer (score 12):

If your Docker MySQL host is running correctly you can connect to it from local machine, but you should specify host, port and protocol like this:

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root
```

Because you are running MySQL inside Docker container, socket is not available and you need to connect through TCP. Setting "--protocol" in the mysql command will change that.

Comment: this answer work for me.  I was running mysql workbench and although my host were different in workbench localhost still worked to connect.

Comment: This is not that suitable in most cases, as you would need to have mysql tools to be installed on the machine you want to get access from.

There are many cases in which user might have mysql in container only.

Answer (score 3):

You can just Use `--network="host"` in your docker run command, then `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` in your docker container will point to your docker host.

```
docker run --network="host" -p 8080:8080 <your-docker-Image>
```

Comment: Host networking doesn't work on MacOS or Windows hosts (this question specifically mentions a MacOS host).  Since it totally disables Docker's networking layer, it's not usually a recommended approach.

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me.

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

Comment: Can you explain it in more details how exactly does it work and where was it used?

Comment: thats the location where mysql is installed. so the command "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql" will run the mysql executable. just mysql on its own wont work in some cases as it depends on how you installed mysql on your mac

Comment: I used it on a mysql 5.7 container running via docker-compose and used it with a docker swarm using docker-machine

Answer (score 1):

Your yml file looks good.

You can directly connect docker container directly as it already mapped with local port 3306.
Just goto terminal and run

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

Note: you must have access to mysql command line. If mysql command show an error, check '/usr/local/mysql/bin' other wise you can not connect to mysql server. In other word you must have mysql client on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to MySQL via {host ip}:3306 since you've exposed the internal port to your host as 3306.  If you need to access the MySQL CLI tools you will need to go `docker exec -it mycontainer bash` this will place you inside the container to access the tools installed with MySQL if you do not have them installed locally on the host o/s.

Comment: good answer, default mysql docker image has mysql-client tools (checked on tag 5.6, 5.7)