# spring boot wont connect to MYSQL database using Intellij

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-boot, database-connection

please help me i spended 2 days on this small problem and i don't know how to solve it yet.

i have installed mysql in a docker container in my local windows 10 PC.

mysql server is working fine (running from MySQL Workbench)

but when i try to run from intellij these error messages apear.

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar=5500:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\poservice\target\classes;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.2.3\logback-classic-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.2.3\logback-core-1.2.3.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.10.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.10.0\log4j-api-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\1.7.25\jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\javax\annotation\javax.annotation-api\1.3.2\javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.19\snakeyaml-1.19.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-aop-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\javax.transaction-api\1.2\javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\5.2.17.Final\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.3.2.Final\jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persistence\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api\1.0.2.Final\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.22.0-GA\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.0.3.Final\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.3.4\classmate-1.3.4.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\5.0.1.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\2.0.10.RELEASE\spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.0.10.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.25\slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-aspects-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\2.7.9\HikariCP-2.7.9.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-security-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.0.8.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.0.8.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.6\jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.6\jackson-core-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.9.6\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.9.6\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\8.5.34\tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\8.5.34\tomcat-embed-el-8.5.34.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\8.5.34\tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\6.0.12.Final\hibernate-validator-6.0.12.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\javax\validation\validation-api\2.0.1.Final\validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-web-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.47\mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.16.22\lombok-1.16.22.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.0.9.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.0.8.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar" com.darelweb.poservice.PoserviceApplication

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

    2018-09-22 12:25:00.839  INFO 22552 --- [           main] c.d.poservice.PoserviceApplication       : Starting PoserviceApplication on rm-lt-w10-p50 with PID 22552 (C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\poservice\target\classes started by lenovo in C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\poservice)
    2018-09-22 12:25:00.843  INFO 22552 --- [           main] c.d.poservice.PoserviceApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2018-09-22 12:25:00.889  INFO 22552 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@75c072cb: startup date [Sat Sep 22 12:25:00 GMT+01:00 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-09-22 12:25:01.925  INFO 22552 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5e92af76] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.569  INFO 22552 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.595  INFO 22552 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.595  INFO 22552 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.34
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.599  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm;.]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.705  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.706  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1821 ms
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.810  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.811  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.811  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.811  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.811  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.812  INFO 22552 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
    2018-09-22 12:25:02.970  INFO 22552 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2018-09-22 12:25:04.118 ERROR 22552 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

    java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3978) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3914) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1714) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1224) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2199) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2230) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2025) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:778) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar:5.1.47]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) [spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) [spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) [spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) [spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) [spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:166) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:111) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d6971e5.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4() [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d6971e5$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d9119109.invoke() [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:365) [spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7d6971e5.jpaVendorAdapter() [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:474) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1247) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1096) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
        at com.darelweb.poservice.PoserviceApplication.main(PoserviceApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]

    2018-09-22 12:25:04.127  WARN 22552 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

    org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:328) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:356) ~[spring-jdbc-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]

    Process finished with exit code 1
```

my application.proprieties file :

```
    spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poservicedb?useSSL=false

    spring.datasource.username = root
    spring.datasource.password = pos

    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
    spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1


    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

my pom.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.darelweb</groupId>
    <artifactId>poservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>poservice</name>
    <description>point of sales saas application</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Take a deeper look in that: `java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`...

Comment: the user name and password are correct but it wont connect

Comment: That was not the question. The issue is related to the configuration of your DB...apart from that you shouldn't connect to a database with user `root` ...better find another username and configure your database accordingly...

Comment: i did it, but the same error message apear (please help)

Comment: I don't think, anyone can help you much. Because as per exception, `root` is not allowed to access your db. So, either you validate the password or your datasource url.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL using command line or any client with root/pos?

Comment: Can you try removing spring-boot-starter-jdbc as you already have jpa

Comment: +techtabu yes i am able to connect

Comment: + kj007 thank you but nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i checked my task manager i found another mysql process working

after i closed it the error was solved

thank you

Answer (score 0):

When Docker runs MySQL, you have to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. This is because when a MySQL client tries to connect to localhost, it looks for the socket file descriptor instead of using TCP/IP.

It's explained in this post here: [Connect to Docker MySQL container from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost)

Comment: thank you for answearing me, but the problem persist even after changing it to 127.0.0.1 i really don't know why