# PhpStorm - How to connect to MySQL via Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, phpstorm

I am working with PhpStorm 2018.3.4, Docker, MySQL and Ubuntu.
I tried unsuccessfully to configure MySQL with the Docker container `network_mysql`.

First, I have tried this configuration :

[image: First configuration]

It gave me this error :

[image: Result of the first configuration]

Then, I tried this :

[image: Second configuration]

This one gave me this other error.

[image: Result of the second configuration]

Am I missing something? Is there another place where I must configure something?

`docker ps` output :

[image: docker ps]

Here `docker network ls` :

[image: docker network ls]

For the command `docker inspect network_mysql`, here is a link to the description :
https://pastebin.com/9LmeAkc8

Here is a docker-compose.yml configuration : 
https://pastebin.com/DB4Eye4y

I tried to put `- "3306:3306"` in addition to the `wex_server_proxy` section with no avail.

The file to modify was this one :

https://pastebin.com/TPBQNCDZ

I added the `ports` section, opening the 3306 port :) And then, it works.

Comment: use your mysql container name  in connection host

Comment: you can see the container name by this command docker ps or docker container ls

Comment: typo `mysql:///` three slashes, should be 2 ?

Comment: Can you share your container configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connect to Docker MySQL container from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost)

Comment: The container name is `network_mysql`. But i see '/network_mysql` in the Docker section of PHPStorm. It is for that reason that i tested `/network_mysql` and then got `mysql:///`. We have a layout with Docker so it is a bit complicated, i am not the creator of this layout.

Comment: post your output when `docker  ps` ? And I am very certain you don't need three slashes.

Comment: I just added the output of `docker ps`.

Comment: and `docker network ls` please?

Comment: and `docker inspect network_mysql` sorry, for doing that one by one, but that is all info required to understand how to access your mysql container. Do you have any other tool connected to that DB except phpstorm?

Comment: by the way you don't need `network` at the end of connection link but just: `jdbc:mysql://network_mysql:3306`

Comment: I added the `docker network ls` but for `docker inspect network_mysql` it shows too much information on the project like password so ... no :) It is PhpStorm that puts `network` at the end when we give it the database name.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## **Solution**

I notice that you are not mapping the mysql container port out. If you did, you would see this from the `docker ps` command:

```
...   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp       network_mysql
```

[image: Post not mapped out for mysql container]

The container `network_mysql` is attached to a bridge type network called `tmp_wex_net`. This means that the container is not accesible from the host, by it's container name.

I appears that you are using a docker-compose.yml definition for the stack. In order to be able to access the container from the host, you need to use the `ports` section of your compose definition for this container:

```
serivces:
  mysql:
    ...
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    ...
```

If you are starting it with `docker run`, then you can acomplish the same thing with:

```sh
docker run -p 3306:3306 --name network_mysql --network="tmp_wex_net" -d mysql
```

And then use `localhost` in the hostname of your connection settings in PHPStorm. Like this:

> **Host**: localhost
>
> **Port**: 3306
>
> **Database**: network

---

## **The problem**

The reason that you are not able to connect, is that the host name `network_mysql` that you specify in the connection settings, does not resolve to any host that your machines knows of.

The container name of a docker container, is not a DNS name that the docker host can resolve.

If you have not specified any network for your mysql container, then it is connected to the default bridge network. And if you have created a new network, without specifying the type - it will also default to the bridge driver.

In order to access the container from the host, you need to either:

1. Connect the container to the host network
2. Or from a container on a bridge network, map the port to the host like suggested in the solution above. You can then address the specifically mapped port on that container with `localhost:<portnum>` from the host machine.

Comment: I added the `docker inspect network_mysql` command via a link in my original post.

Comment: I can see that your container is in the 'tmp_wex_net' network which is a bridge network. Please try my instructions in the bottom of my answer. I think I will move them to the top.

Comment: I edited my answer to fit the new information, and to make the solution appear in the top of the answer. Let me know if the suggested solution works out for you.

Comment: I will discuss of your solution with the one who created the overlay.

Comment: I changed something to the Docker configuration file (that i just added to my post) but it did not change anything.

Comment: Port 443 does not have anything to do with what you are trying to do. And the containers specified in the docker-compose.yml definition that you have added, do not have anything to do with the mysql container. You will have to show the docker-compose.yml where you define the `mysql` service, and add `- "3306:3306"` to the `ports` section in there.

Comment: Whoops, i meant 3306 ah ah. I edited my post ! I will try to find other Docker configuration files.

Comment: Ok i found the good section in another Docker file. Thanks for all :D

Answer (score 3):

For everyone who has setup mysql manually in a docker image:

chances are you must configure mysql to accept incoming connections also from the network interface which docker creates/uses to communicate with the host (along with port forwarding).

in my case, i added the following to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to the end of the file:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address    = 0.0.0.0
```

With that mysql listens on all network interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
I forwarded ports from localhost to remote: `ssh -R 3306:localhost:3306 root@remote_host_ip` and the connection was successful.