# Cannot connect to mysql in Docker container from host

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm running a Docker mysql container on my Mac laptop. Previously I was able to connect to it from the host OS with the mysql client. However, somehow it got deleted, and now after I re-created it, I can no longer to connect to it. I've searched dozens of similar questions, but am completely stumped.

Here's how I created it:

```
docker container run --name mysql-zhxw-dev -p 3306:3306 --expose=3306 -v zhxw-local-db-:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -d mysql:5.7.30
```

Every time I run `mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1` the following from my host OS, I get:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)
```

I can login to the container, and connect to mysql from within:

```
docker container exec -it mysql-zhxw-dev bash
mysql -u root <-- connects fine
```

I've tried:

- Omitting the named volume
- Specifying a password
- Various versions of mysql, including 5.6 and 5.7
- Logging in to the container with `docker container exec`, installing `vi`, editing /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf and uncommenting the line that contains `bind-address`. I tried it with both `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` and `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`, then obviously exiting and running `docker container restart mysql-zhxw-dev`.
- Specifying port to connect to with `-P 3306`
- Connecting with `-h localhost`, `-h 127.0.0.1`, `-h 0.0.0.0`, and omitting the `-h`
- Specifying `--protocol=TCP` when connecting

I'm at a loss as to what else to try.

Comment: Have you tried connecting on the IP address of the Docker container? Use `docker inspect <container-id> | grep inet` to find the IP address.

Comment: I tried `docker container inspect mysql-zhxw-dev | grep inet`, but there were no lines that contained "inet". So I searched for "ip" instead, and there were a couple an `IPAddress` entries in the `NetworkSettings` object. (Both the same IP.) I tried connecting that way (`mysql -u root -h 172.17.0.2`) but it didn't respond at at all - just timed-out.

Answer (score 1):

i have a template in docker-compose with mysql, maybe it can help you.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - /path-persistent-volumen:/var/lib/mysql/
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this purely with docker - not with docker-compose, since this is just for local development, and I already have a docker-compose.yml file for the full environment on this project.

Comment: the key point is `--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`
for a newer version of MySQL, use`--authentication_policy=*` can work

Answer (score 1):

It turns out docker must have been in a strange state. Rebooting my laptop solved the problem.

Before rebooting, I tried restarting Docker Desktop, and that did not fix it. Only a full reboot resolved it.

One thing that I did notice was before the reboot, when I ran `docker container ls -a`, there were no containers, apart from the one mysql one I was trying to get working. I thought I had perhaps pruned them from some cleanup command. After the reboot, all my containers came back.

I did recently upgrade docker using Homebrew, so perhaps that put it in a weird state.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs due to problems related to port on the host.

Try these things:

1. Check logs of the container
2. Start the container in attached mode using `-a` flag
3. Run `docker inspect mysql-zhxw-dev` and check HostPort and HostIp and try to find something anomalous.
4. You can also change the host port in port mapping to something else like `-v 3308:3306`.

Also, this might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/32361238/9586997

P.S. I have copied and run the same command you have given, and it is running fine.

Comment: Thanks - actually I figured it out. My docker was in some kind of broken state. Rebooting fixed it. (I posted an answer that starts with "It turns out docker must have been in a strange state....")

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after modifying the docker images and container configuration.  Turns out the local copy of the MySQL data instance was corrupt.

Removing the ./data directory noted in this compose file and rebuilding worked.

The compose file

```
# /docker/docker-compose.yml
---
services:
  db:
    container_name: 'wp-mysql'
    image: 'mysql:5.7.37'
    platform: linux/amd64
    volumes:
      - './data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    ports:
      - "18766:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress_db
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress_password
```

The rebuild command for docker

```
docker-compose -f "docker-compose.yml" up -d --build
```