# Connect from WSL2 to a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm trying to connect, from WSL2, to a MySQL DB hosted in a docker container. I can reach the container from Windows side, but I cannot reach the container from WSL side.

I've found several answers that explain how to connect from container to container, from [windows to the container or from the container to windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds), but no clear way of reaching a container from WSL2.

I've connected to the DB using Workbench from Windows side without any problem. But if I try connecting to the DB from Ubuntu `mysql -h host.docker.internal -p 3306 -u THE_USERNAME -pTHE_PASSWORD` (Yes I've checked the credentials and port are ok) I get `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host.docker.internal' (110)`. Also tried using `localhost` instead of host.docker.internal, but I get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

If I ran `docker ps` I can clearly see the container running with the correct ports set. For what I've read I should be using `host.docker.internal`, however  in the Ubuntu hosts file it's mapped to some ip which I cannot reach from WSL, but can reach from windows side.

I have the following set up:
The whole setup was done following the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers).

- Windows 10 Pro Version 2004 Build 19041
- WSL2 w/ Ubuntu 20.04
- Docker Desktop WSL2 backend (with WSL2 integration enabled)

The containers docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.26
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 
    volumes:
      - mydata:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./:/home/xx/yy/zz
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - local_network
networks:
    local_network:
volumes:
  mydata:
```

Everything points that it's a networking - naming problem, but I cannot find nothing related...
Any help would be appreciated :D

Comment: I've found a workaround, according to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360687/connect-to-docker-mysql-container-from-localhost?rq=1) using `docker-compose up` should work...but in my case it doesn't, but after running `docker-compose run --service-ports <service_name>` I could connect using `127.0.0.1` instead of `host.docker.internal`, which I would rather use...

Comment: Kinda same setup here but connecting to postgresql. answer worked for me: `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432` from inside the WSL2 Ubuntu to a postgres docker running on the windows 10 host. Port 5232 was mapped out of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capital letter P for the port and a lowercase letter p for the password:

```
mysql -h host.docker.internal -P 3306 -u THE_USERNAME -pTHE_PASSWORD
```